# 葉が四枚になったところで、大きい植木鉢に植え替えた。

Tags: meaning, transitivity

> 葉が四枚になったところで、大きい植木鉢に植え替えた。毎日どんどん(a)ーーーーー、とても楽しみだった。
>
> そのうち、蔓が伸びてきた。棒を立てて、この蔓を巻いてやった。折れないように注意しながら、伸びた部分をなるべく横に(b)ーーーーーといいそうだ。

For selection b there are 2 choices:
1 - 広げる
2 - 広がっていく

I chose the 2 which was wrong, selection 1 is correct. Why is the 他動詞 広げる correct and the 自動詞 - 広がっていく wrong? The plant will twine around the pole itself, correct?

Comment: Are you sure that the answers/options are copied correctly ? For (a) it looks like 2 as well; (b), it should be 広げると.

Comment: @sundowner  You are correct *(a) is 2 and (b) is 1.   Can you tell me why 2 is 広げる?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> そのうち、蔓が伸びてきた。棒を立てて、この蔓を巻いてやった。折れないように注意しながら、**伸びた部分を**なるべく横に(b)ーーーーーといいそうだ。
> 1 - 広げる
> 2 - 広がっていく

The correct choice is #1, transitive 広げる, because there is direct object 伸びた部分**を**. The unmentioned subject is 人 (the speaker or generic you), not the plant. It's 人が[subject] + (蔓の)伸びた部分を[direct object] + (横に)広げる[transitive verb].